# Do both Ikaros and Nymph have ears or just Astrea?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

I haven't seen the movie yet, but I finished the show multiple times and have never seen either Ikaros' or Nymph's ears. Why is that?

Comment: Hidden under their hair, perhaps?

Comment: I think the things on the top of Astrea's head are decorative wings rather than her actual ears.

Comment: I thought the bell shaped objects beside her head were like robotic ears?

Answer (score 1):

They're almost never seen but Ikaros' ears are behind her hair.

[image: Ikaros]
<sub>From manga chapter 28</sub>

But Nymph probably doesn't have ears
[image: Nymph]
<sub>From manga chapter 25</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The protruding robotic wings on Nymph's head and Astrea's head are their ears because they have been used to communicate. Following this principle whereby the bell-shaped objects on Ikaros's head receive speech, those wings are their ears. I have never seen actual ears but those seem to fill the job. Also it shows that Ikaros uses those as ears which I hope provides some of the answer you are looking for.